# ChangeDetectionStrategy do Angular

Tags: angular, angular-6, angular-5

Ao estudar Angular 6 estava vendo que ele possui estratégias diferentes de como o component é atualizado conforme os Eventos, XHR e Observables dentro da minha aplicação.

Depois de muita pesquisa não achei nenhum conteúdo em português sobre essa questão.

Gostaria de saber se no Angular 4+ mudou a forma de como ele atualiza os components e se é interessante e performático mudar a estratégia de detecção de mudança (ChangeDetectionStrategy) conforme a necessidade.

Caso alguém tenha links uteis sobre a questão já agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O angular tem dois tipos de **ChangeDetectionStrategy** o **Default** e o **OnPush**. A principal diferenca e que o OnPush funciona somente com objetos e arrays imutaveis. Ou seja somente se for passado outra referencia a change detection do OnPush sera trigered. Sendo assim funciona muito bem com observables ja que vc pode tratar qualquer mudanca de uma variavel como algo como o 'next; num subject no qual cada mudanca retorna um novo objeto e o anterior e descartado.

Exemplo:

```
@Component({
  ....
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MeuOnPushComponent {
     pessoa:Pessoa = {
        nome: 'Jose',
        idade: 15
    }

    mudarNome(){
       this.pessoa.nome='Joao'; // Nao triger a change detection do OnPush pois a referencia e a mesma (seria detectado no default)
    }

   mudarPessoa(){
       this.pessoa={
        nome: 'Joao',
        idade: 20
    }; // Triger a change detection do OnPush pois a referencia muda para um novo objeto
  }

 }
```

Comment: Vlw Eduardo, esclareceu para mim!